# how to show only non zero data value in bar highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Data returned from the server contains columns with zero values. If i show all the values the chart is not in readable format so i want only the columns with non zero values to be displayed on the highchart

Comment: you can use an array where you can store and save only values above zero! Use that array to set up your chart. How is the data sent?

Comment: 1) you need to process your data, and remove the unwanted values.  2) make sure that removing 0 values actually makes sense in terms of viewing the data - don't do it just to make the chart look better.